# How to translate a vector and then rotate by a point

Tags: geometry, rotations, rigid-transformation

I am trying to do this problem:

> Identify the combination formed by first translating by the vector
>   $(2,0)$ and then rotating by $90$ degrees about $(0,0)$.

but I'm a bit confused so,

I searched online where it said:

> For the rotation,by an angle
>   $\theta$ about point $P$. This can be replaced by two reflections by
>   lines at an angle $\theta/2$ which intersect at P. 
>   The translation by a distance $t$ can be replaced by reflections by two
>   parallel lines at a distance of $t/2$, where the lines are
>   perpendicular to the direction of the translation.
>
> The second line of the rotation can be made equal to the first line of
>   the translation. Thus they cancel in the composition, leaving only the
>   first line of the rotation and the second line of the translation.
>   This is a rotation through the point of intersection of these two
>   lines.

However, as I was reading online, I read how translating and rotating is not commutative. Therefore, the above procedure only helps me when I rotate first then translate next. So what happens when I translate a vector then rotate as in the problem mentioned above.

Comment: If you translate first, make the _first_ reflection of the rotation coincide with the _second_ reflection of the translation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $T$ denotes your translation by $(2,0)$, and $R$ your rotation by $90^\circ$ around the origin, then your map is $Q=R\circ T$. You can find $Q$ either analytically or geometrically.

**Analytic solution**

$T$ and $R$ are defined by
$$
T(x)=x+(2,0)=(x_1+2,x_2), \, R(x)=(-x_2,x_1) \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^2.
$$
Therefore
$$
Q(x)=R(T(x))=R(x_1+2,x_2)=(-x_2,x_1+2) \quad \forall x=(x_1,x_2)\in \mathbb{R}^2
$$
Notice that $Q$ has exactly one fixed point, i.e. $a=(-1,1)$. In fact $Q(x)=x \iff x=(-1,1)$ and therefore $Q$ is a rotation.

For every $x\in \mathbb{R}^2$ we have
$$
(x-a)\cdot(Q(x)-a)=(x_1+1,x_2-1)\cdot(-x_2+1,x_1+1)=0,
$$
i.e. $(x-a)\perp (Q(x)-a)$, and therefore $Q$ is a rotation by $90^\circ$ around the point $a=(-1,1)$.

**Geometric solution**
If $\Delta\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is a straight line, we denote by $S_\Delta$ the reflection about $\Delta$.  We can then write
$$
T=S_{L_0}\circ S_{L_1}, \quad R=S_{L_2}\circ S_{L_0},
$$
with
\begin{eqnarray}
L_0&=&\{(x_1,x_2)\in \mathbb{R}^2:\, x_1=0 \},\\ 
L_1&=&\{(x_1,x_2)\in \mathbb{R}^2:\, x_1=1 \},\\
L_2&=&\{(x_1,x_2)\in \mathbb{R}^2:\, x_2=-x_1 \}
\end{eqnarray}
We have
$$
Q=R\circ T=(S_{L_2}\circ S_{L_0})\circ(S_{L_0}\circ S_{L_1})=S_{L_2}\circ (\underbrace{S_{L_0}\circ S_{L_0}}_{\mbox{identity}})\circ S_{L_1}=S_{L_2}\circ S_{L_1}
$$
Since the two lines $L_1$ and $L_2$ intersect at the point $a=(1,-1)$ and the angle $(L_1,L_2)$ between $L_1$ and $L_2$ is $45^\circ$, it follows that $Q$ is a rotation by $2\times45^\circ=90^\circ$ around the point $a=(-1,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Matrix Multiplication (not commutative!) Indeed, all isometries can be represented as 3 reflections, but not all isometries are rotations, translations, and reflections.